# What is the best approach to deal with the iphone 5 & 4/4S/3G Screen Resulotion

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, interface-builder, uistoryboard

i am looking for the best and correct approach when dealing with user interface design from a `UIStoryBoard`. as you guessed correct the problem is with the different aspect ratio between the iPhone 5 to all of the older iPhones. some people using 2 different `UIStoryBoard` in the app and loading the correct one when the app launched, this will work. but when i will want to make a change now i have to deal with 2 files. the other approach is `AutoLayout`.
so what do you think is the most efficient \ time convenient when dealing with user interface inside a StoryBoard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two storyboards isn't very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and so will result in duplicated effort and files that get out of sync. Additionally, it isn't capable of quickly handling any new screen dimensions that Apple could release.

It is better to use AutoLayout or the older AutoResize. Apple has been pushing AutoLayout increasingly and has improved it with XC5 and iOS 7. Keep your UI, and your code, DRY and embrace the clear path that Apple has laid out to handle this.